# replace appSetting value with value of an environment property defined in aws Elastic Beanstalk during deployment

Tags: asp.net, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In my ASP.NET webapp (not asp.net core), I have a simple setting in my `web.config`

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Name" value="local"/>
  </appSettings>
```

This webapp is hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, on my server, I have an environment property defined as

[image]

my question is, during deployment, I want the value of appSetting "Name" in my web.config to be replaced as "server" (the value of the environment property).

How to achieve this? I tried a few things in my .ebextension script but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

Again, I am answering my own question. Here is what I found out.

During deployment, aws will add the environment properties to web.config as app settings. But only if there is no existing app setting with the same name.

More concretely, the "Name" environment property in my screenshot will be added to web.config as

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="Name" value="server"/>
  </appSettings>
```

if there is no existing app setting with name = "Name" in it.

There is no clear doc for this behavior, but this is what I found in Nov 2019.